# csvkit in2csv command not working

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, csvkit

I followed installment instructions mentioned [here](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/install.html)
Its a simple `pip install` command

After that I went to my linux terminal and wrote `in2csv`but got the following error:
`/usr/bin/in2csv: No such file or directory`

Originally I tried to install it using the command:
`sudo apt-get install python3-csvkit`
And the `in2csv` command used to work on terminal, but it appears to work under python 3 installation and I need it under my python2.7.

so I uninstalled the `python3-csvkit`, and installed it again using pip install, but again its not working from terminal, this way.

Any ideas why, and how to solve it?

`in2csv` command manual: [here](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/scripts/in2csv.html)

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem and solved with:

```
sudo pip install csvkit
```

Without the sudo pip installs csvkit in /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and probably puts the executable in /home/username/.local/bin.  You could avoid the sudo by adding that to your shell PATH.